# A reliable Anti-virus that only scans?

Tags: anti-virus

I'm looking for a good anti-virus that only scans for files (preferably from context-menu) and doesn't run in the background or at least offers an option to disable that and has really low ram consumption. (10MB~20MB). Dont mention online scanners cause uploading files to scan is a bother.
Suggesions?

Comment: There's [ClamWim](http://www.clamwin.com/), for example. Product recommendations are off-topic, though. Consider asking here instead: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can disable on-access scanning in [Sophos](http://www.sophos.com/) (which also happens to be [free on macs](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-mac-home-edition.aspx)), however I strongly recommend against this.

### Why I can't recommend disabling on-access scanning...

Background on-access scanning runs so that, as soon as malicious information hits your system, it is purged. The problem with disabling this is that a significant aspect of most malware is that it does irreparable damage or hides itself; the longer it remains on a system, the more time it has to hide itself or completely ruin your system. Which means that, by the time you get around to scanning your entire filesystem, the malware could have done any of the following (to provide only a few examples):

1. Encrypted all of your files, rendering them unreadable -- Malware that does this is most often "ransomware", which demands payment from you within a time limit or you lose all
   your information. By the time you notice it exists on your system,
   it's already too late.
2. Bound itself to important system files -- A lot of malware will use [file binders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_binder) which make it impossible to remove the malware without removing or damaging programs you care about.
3. Sent all of your personal information to whatever criminals wrote / deployed the malware -- This includes, but is not limited to, banking and e-mail passwords, information from you webcam and microphone, and files on your system.
4. Hidden itself within parts of your filesystem AV scanners can't / don't normally go, or within firmware (which a full reinstall of the operating system won't fix).
5. Subverted / disabled / uninstalled your AV (leaving you with no way of knowing your machine is infected, and definitely no easy way to fix it).
6. Used your computer as a proxy for something illegal in your country (e.g. downloading child pornography, DoSsing or hacking into some website, threatening someone or stealing from them) -- If you're lucky, the malware won't erase itself afterward, and you can use its presence as a legal defense. Of course, the legal costs and investment of time on your part will still be extensive. If you're less lucky, the malware will have erased itself, you'll be found guilty, and will have to do time in prison (maybe state; probably federal).
7. Something else entirely.
8. Any and all of the above.